# Error When Writing to Firestore "Cannot bind a list to map for field 'fields'."

Tags: r, firebase, post, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firebase project with a firestore database. I am trying to write a JSON object to a document in it using a POST request in R:

```
write.db <- function(db_endpoint, data, auth_token) {
  r <- POST(db_endpoint,
             add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/json",
                         "Authorization" = paste("Bearer", auth_token)), body = data)
  return(r)
}
```

The JSON object is formatted as follows:

```
{
   fields: [
      {obj1}
      {obj2}
      ...
   ]
}
```

Every time I try to write this data to the document, I get the below error:

```
"error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid value at 'document' (Map), Cannot bind a list to map for field 'fields'.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
...
```

Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue is with the `json` format. It contains a `list` instead of a `dictionary` or `maps` which should have a key-value pair as described in this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types#:%7E:text=64%2Dbit%2C%20signed-,Map,-By%20keys%2C%20then).

If you have multiple values for same collection, Try :

```
{
   fields: [
      {
       obj1 : value1,
       obj2 : value1 
      },
      {
       obj1 : value2,
       obj2 : value 2
       }
      ...
   ]
}
```

Instead of :

```
{
   fields: [
      {obj1}
      {obj2}
      ...
   ]
}
```

Another example from [this article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/firebase-import-json-to-firestore-ed6a4adc2b57#:%7E:text=Download%20Zip-,users.json,-%7B%0A%20%20%22users%22%3A%20%5B) which has multiple values for collection users:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "firstName": "Kristin",
      "lastName": "Smith",
      "occupation": "Teacher",
      "reviewCount": "6",
      "reviewScore": "5",
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "firstName": "Olivia",
      "lastName": "Parker",
      "occupation": "Teacher",
      "reviewCount": "11",
      "reviewScore": "5"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: hmmm I don't fully understand. In the example you posted, why is obj2 posted twice? Is that intentional?

Comment: @AndrewColin Unintentionally I made mistakes. I have updated my answers, can you have a look at it?